# using C Shared library not built with NDK in Android APK development

Tags: android, static-libraries

I have a query regarding using prebuilt library in android APK development,

I have a C Static library not built with NDK in Android APK development, but this is build with standard library build procedure for required ARM target, i have the header file declaring the function definitions, how can i include this header file & link the symbols with static library in Android application(APK) programming using SDK.

Thanks,
SK

Answer (score -1):

Did you already look at docs/PREBUILTS.html in your ndk directory?